# Removing hyphens in Safari with css

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to remove hyphens with css. This has worked for everything, but Safari. Is there anyone who could help me with why and how to fix it, please?

```
.selector {
  moz-hyphens: none !important;
  ms-hyphens: none !important;
  webkit-hyphens: none !important;
  hyphens: none !important;
}
```

Thanks, Nikki

Comment: vendor prefix always start with '-' so try to replace `webkit-hyphens: none !important;` with  `-webkit-hyphens: none !important;`

Comment: That worked perfectly - thanks for pointing it out :)